# How much more lore is covered in the fire and ice books?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, adaptation-comparison

If you watch the HBO series and get curious about something, you can quickly get pulled into a super deep rabbit hole of Westeros lore by following random links on for instance [this wiki](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Main_Page) - detailed explanations of just briefly mentioned characters such as [Ser Arthur Dayne](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Arthur_Dayne) or dudes not mentioned at all such as Daemon Blackfyre. I kind of assumed this was all covered in the books (which I haven't read), but by reading the summaries, it doesn't seem possible for them to cover all this really deep, intricate lore that is covered on the wiki.

But this is just my impression - am I mistaken in this assumption? How much more is covered by the books as compared to the show?

Comment: Possibly see also [my own humble question along similar lines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59005/are-there-sources-for-a-song-of-ice-and-fire-other-than-the-books). Note that the books are ridiculously long.

Comment: @GuesAccount, you might also be interested in reading the [Tag Wiki for ASOIAF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/a-song-of-ice-and-fire/info)

Comment: A lot much more.